# Is this a variety of banana slug (Ariolimax columbianus)? (California)

Tags: species-identification, species, molluscs

These very dark (dark grey to black) banana slugs are an anomaly. I live on the north coast of California and see many slugs every day. These particular slugs I find only on the west-facing headlands at the ocean. There is no cover from the sun since there are no plants taller than about a foot. Also these particular slugs are never longer than 2-1/2" to 3". Are they a sub species, a variety, or something else? Thanks for taking the time to answer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Banana slugs are comprised of three species:

- *Ariolimax californicus*
- *Ariolimax columbianus*
- *Ariolimax dolichophallus*

*Ariolimax columbianus*, or the Pacific banana slug is known to have black spots, sometimes so large as to cover their entire body ([Source](http://www.centralcoastbiodiversity.org/banana-slug-bull-ariolimax-columbianus.html)). This is certainly the genus of the slug you've shared.

At times, you could be seeing a [Black slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_slug) which is well-established in Washington and Oregon. I only include this information as I have noticed this species occasionally in Southern British Columbia and wondered if it was the same species as the Banana slug. It isn't. The picture you've attached is not a Black slug (note the pronounced frills on the back of the Black slug specimen)

[image]